# Getting data from session attribute returns null pointer

Tags: java, servlets

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String name = request.getParameter("name"); // get param
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // create list

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(); // create a session handler object

    // if this is new session , add the param to the list, then set the list as session atr

    if(session.isNew()) {
        System.out.println("in new session");
        // this is a new session , add the param to the new list, then add list to session atr
        list.add(name);
        session.setAttribute("list", list);

    }else{

        System.out.println("in old session");
        // THIS SESSION ALREADY EXISTS (THERE IS DATA IN LIST THAT WE NEED, THAT DATA IS STORED IN SESSION ATR)

        // get the session atr , then store the content of a atr list, to this new list
        list = (List<String>)session.getAttribute("list");

        // add the new item to the list
        list.add(name);

        // set the new session atr, now with this newly added item
        session.setAttribute("list", list);


    }
```

Pretty much my comments say it all. I redirect from jsp page from where a from is submitted, get the name , create a list and session handler.

Point of this program is saving user input in a list. Obviously, I need sessions so I can make difference between users and have different lists for different users. I get null pointer exception in else statement where I try to retrieve an already existing list so I can add more items in it. What am I missing ? Thanks

Comment: The session may have been created elsewhere. So instead of relying on whether or not the session is new, check whether it contains that attribute.

Comment: A JSP will **always** (unless explicitly configured not to) create a session when accessed. Your test is not sufficient - drop it and simply add the attribute if absent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's indeed not the right approach of maintaining a session scoped object. You're relying on `HttpSession#isNew()` which would only return `true` when the HTTP session is new, not when the session scoped object is absent. If the session has already (implicitly) been created before the servlet is invoked, then `isNew()` would return `false`. For example, when you've opened a JSP page without `<%@page session="false" %>` beforehand in the same session.

You should instead be checking if the session scoped object of interest is present or not.

So, instead of:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

if (session.isNew()) {
    list.add(name);
    session.setAttribute("list", list);
} else {
    list = (List<String>) session.getAttribute("list");
    list.add(name);
    session.setAttribute("list", list);
}
```

You should be doing like:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
List<String> list = (List<String>) session.getAttribute("list");

if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    session.setAttribute("list", list);
}

list.add(name);
```

Do note that you **do not** need to put that list back in the session. The session does not hold a copy of the `List` object or so, as you'd expect in procedural languages like PHP. Java is an object oriented language. The session holds a copy of the **reference** to the `List` object. All changes to mutable objects like `List` are reflected back in all references.

To learn how the HTTP session works under the covers, head to [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-shared-variables-and-multithreading).

Comment: Thanks,for solving my problem, and also for providing me with a correct way of handling these kind of things.